# Add Windows 11 tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I noticed while writing a question about Windows 11 that we don't have a Windows 11 tag.  Since Windows 11 released this morning, the tag should be made for people who have questions about Windows 11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since Windows 11 released this morning, the tag should be made for people who have questions about Windows 11.

Windows 11 was announced it was not actually released.  However, [I already created it](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-11), it's a shell of a tag since most of the stuff that exists in the Windows 10 tag cannot be added to the tag at this time.

I also created a [Windows 11 Preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-11-preview) tag which matches the Windows-10-Preview tag.

Comment: We can use the Windows-Insider tag to properly tag questions about preview builds of Windows 11.  We probably should have avoided creating a Windows 11 tag this early, since it's not released, and won't be for several months.  However, there have already been nearly 6 questions, specifically about it probably would have been created by somebody else.

Comment: I'm wondering if the windows-11 tag should, for the moment, be merged and synonymised with the windows-11-preview tag. For the moment all there is are previews, there is no de-facto Windows 11 release.

Comment: @Mokubai - If we do that cannot be reversed?  What happens in 4 months when it is released?  It’s a pain but we could just handle that cleanup manually.  There can’t possibly be that many questions about TPM requirements for Windows 11 :$

Comment: @Ramhound it would mean that existing and current new questions would all be tagged as "preview", but we can break the synonym later or even merge or retag existing questions into the new tag when it is properly released. For now all we really have are "previews" so from a technical standpoint it seems "right" that everything relating to it is tagged that way.. future me can deal with 4 months away, chump deserves everything he gets.

Comment: @Mokubai - Future me likes the idea; Past me immediately regretted it making the preview tag first. Ancient me figured (better someone who could do a minimum text description than someone who wouldn’t go to that effort). Present me is 3 stooging himself.

Comment: "There can’t possibly be that many questions about TPM requirements for Windows 11 :$" - They're coming in thick and fast.

Comment: @spikey_richie - I immediately regret answering that first TPM question